# Haskell type annotating a simple function to return an array

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to type annotate my function and I am failing. The behavior of the function is correct only type annotation fails.

```
range :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Float]
range from to 0 = [];
range from to count = do
  let increment = fromIntegral(to - from) / count
  let lst = [0] ++ [increment, increment + increment ..]
  take (round count) lst

main = do
  print (range 0 1 10)
```

Error message:

> ```
> main.hs:7:3: error:
>     • Couldn't match type ‘Integer’ with ‘Float’
>       Expected type: [Float]
>         Actual type: [Integer]
>     • In a stmt of a 'do' block: take (round count) lst
>       In the expression:
>         do let increment = fromIntegral (to - from) / count
>            let lst = ... ++ ...
>            take (round count) lst
>       In an equation for ‘range’:
>           range from to count
>             = do let increment = ...
>                  let lst = ...
>                  take (round count) lst
>   |
> 7 |   take (round count) lst
>   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: can you cast your Ints to floats?

Comment: I want to return array of floats or whatever it's called in Haskell

Comment: It's a (linked) list; you can think of both as storing a sequence of items, but *how* each does it has significant consequences for how it behaves and performs.

Comment: FYI, `range` is roughly doing what `enumFromThenTo` already does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the type signature of (/) is `Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, which requires its two arguments to be the same type. So you should apply `fromIntegral` to both `to - from` and `count`.

And the `round` function returns a `RealFrac`, but the first argument of `take` should be `Int`, which is not an instance of `RealFrac`. You can change it to `fromIntegral`.

And you really don't need that much of do-notation ;-)

Here's a version that works:

```hs
range :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Float]
range from to 0 = []
range from to count =
    let increment = fromIntegral(to - from) / fromIntegral count
        lst = 0.0 : [increment, increment + increment ..]
    in take (fromIntegral count) lst

main = print (range 0 1 10)
```